# Unterschied zwischen "Gegensatz" und "Gegenteil"

Tags: difference

Gibt es einen Unterschied zwischen *Gegensatz* und *Gegenteil*? In welcher Situation verwendet man welches Wort?

Comment: Ich sehe nicht ganz, warum die Frage als "too broad" geschlossen werden soll? – Was hier aber definitiv fehlt, ist ein wenig darüber, wo genau das Problem ist. Beispielsätze zum Beispiel. Ein wenig Research? Die Definition sind doch eigentlich recht klar. Die Übersetzung jedoch kann sich überschneiden.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ein Gegensatz ist die Relation zwischen einem Ding und seinem Gegenteil:

- Gegensätze bestehen zwischen groß und klein, zwischen dick und dünn, zwischen arm und reich usw.
- Groß ist das Gegenteil von klein, dick das Gegenteil von dünn, arm das Gegenteil von reich usw.

PS: Man kann *Gegensatz* auch so verwenden, dass es weitgehend synonym zu *Gegenteil* ist:

- Groß ist der Gegensatz zu klein, dick der Gegensatz zu dünn, arm der Gegensatz zu reich usw.

Unabhängig davon, wie sich das Wort *Gegensatz* in der Vergangenheit entwickelt hat, würde ich das aber heute (wahrscheinlich historisch inkorrekt) als eine abgeleitete Verwendung ansehen, in der die Gegensatzrelation zwischen einem Ding und seinem Gegenteil stellvertretend für das Gegenteil selbst genannt wird. Ebenso würde ich "Gegensätze ziehen sich an" nicht direkt als Variante des ungebräuchlichen "Gegenteile ziehen sich an" interpretieren, sondern eher so: "Dinge, die in einer Gegensatz-Relation zueinander stehen, ziehen sich an".

Answer (score 1):

Hinsichtlich ihrer Bedeutungen gibt es oft keinen großartigen Unterschied. Man verwendet sie jedoch unterschiedlich in Sätzen.

*Im Gegenteil* benutzt man alleinstehend, man benutzt es z. B., wenn man sich auf etwas vorher Gesagtes bezieht. Beispiel: „Mir geht es nicht schlecht, ganz im Gegenteil.“

*Im Gegensatz* verwendet man häufig mit *zu* oder falls man sich auf etwas vorher Gesagtes bezieht *dazu* oder *hierzu*. Beispiele: „Im Gegensatz zu dir bin ich sportlich“ oder „Gestern war es schön. Heute hat es im Gegensatz dazu viel geregnet.“

Comment: "leer" ist zu "voll" DAS Gegenteil und EIN Gegensatz... es gibt also schon einen Unterschied in der Bedeutung. -1 für den ersten Satz.

Comment: OK, haben die Wörter abhängig vom Kontext unterschiedliche Bedeutungen. Einmal sind beide an­t­o­nym zueinander und in ihrer Sache sind sie unterschiedlich. Ich habe den ersten Satz mal etwas „abgeschwächt“.

Answer (score -3):

**Gegenteil** steht im direkten sich gegenüberliegendem Verhältnis:

***"Der Teppich ist nicht schwarz, im Gegenteil er ist blau."***

Hier steht die Wahrheit gegenüber der Lüge oder Behauptung.

**Gegensatz** bezieht sich auf eine subjektive Wahrnehmung.

"***Der Teppich ist nicht schwarz, im Gegensatz, er ist eher Dunkelgrau."***

Hier steht die Wahrnehmung einer Person im Gegensatz zu einer anderen Person.

Answer (score -5):

Eigentlich sind die beiden Wörter synonym zueinander. Das Wort *Gegensatz* findet zum Beispiel Verwendung bei Dingen, die zwar unterschiedlich zueinander sind, jedoch nicht das totale Gegenstück.
Zum Beispiel bei Geschwistern: Diese können zwar vom Charakter oder Aussehen her komplett unterschiedlich sein, aber auch nur in gewissen Dingen. Sind sie nicht komplett unterschiedlich zueinander, würde ich eher das Wort *Gegensatz* verwenden. Sind sie sich aber in keiner Weise ähnlich, würde ich das Wort *Gegenteil* verwenden.

Comment: Ich verstehe das Beispiel ehrlich gesagt nicht so ganz. Und "Gegensatz" und "Gegenteil" sind nur bedingt synonym. Austauschbar sind sie wohl recht selten, auch wenn sie prinzipiell eine ähnliche Definition haben.

Comment: Eigentlich sind sie eher nicht synonym.